# How to share cakephp 3.0 while using git

Tags: php, cakephp

I recently installed git for sharing cakephp 3.0 code but after pushing and pulling the browser seems blank then I edit .gitignore file and remove all commands excluding /tem/* because I didn't worry about security right now and then I shared my code and got this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Psr\Log\AbstractLogger' not found in /var/www/html/project/bmw12/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Log/Engine/BaseLog.php on line 24

Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Could not load class Cake\Log\Engine\FileLog in /var/www/html/project/bmw12/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Log/LogEngineRegistry.php:57 Stack trace: #0 
/var/www/html/project/bmw12/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Core/ObjectRegistry.php(91): Cake\Log\LogEngineRegistry->_throwMissingClassError('Cake\\Log\\Engine...', NULL) #1 
/var/www/html/project/bmw12/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Log/Log.php(198): Cake\Core\ObjectRegistry->load('Cake\\Log\\Engine...', Array) #2 
/var/www/html/project/bmw12/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Log/Log.php(180): Cake\Log\Log::_loadConfig() #3 
/var/www/html/project/bmw12/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Log/Log.php(360): Cake\Log\Log::_init() #4 
/var/www/html/project/bmw12/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/BaseErrorHandler.php(284): Cake\Log\Log::write(3, 'Fatal Error (1)...') #5 
/var/www/html/project/bmw12/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/BaseErrorHandler.php(216): Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler->_logError(3, Array) #6 
/var/www/html/project/bmw12/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Bas in /var/www/html/project/bmw12/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Log/LogEngineRegistry.php on line 57
```

Comment: are you running composer install after cloning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I m posting answer for my question, actually its a permission issue in Linux and therefore it doesn't allow to share all the file while using push command in git but while using it doesn't show any error but it doesn't work properly on other end.